# Getting coordinates of dropped div JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having this code:

```
$( init );


function init() {
  $('#makeMeDraggable').draggable( {
  containment: 'window',
 } ); 

}

 function handleDragStop( event, ui ) {

   var offsetXPos = parseInt( ui.offset.left );
   var offsetYPos = parseInt( ui.offset.top ); 
   document.getElementById("X").innerHTML = offsetXPos;
   document.getElementById("Y").innerHTML = offsetYPos;


 }
```

And was just wondering how i call the handleStop - function.

Can't get it to work

Comment: What should the code do? If you don’t specify desired behavior, there can be no bugs (and no features, too).

Comment: Did you read the documentation at all -> **http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop**

Answer (score 0):

You aren't meant to call the drag stop function yourself. Because the draggable behaviour is handled by jQuery, it will do that for you at the appropriate time. You just have to bind it:

```
$('#makeMeDraggable').draggable({
    "containment": 'window',
    "stop": handleDragStop
});
```

Or just

```
$('#makeMeDraggable').on("dragstop", handleDragStop);
```